# How do I click an image without an ID, running a dynamic numeric process?

Tags: html, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I need to automate the deleting of a file for clean up purposes

```
<img src="/images/delete.jpg" class="pointer" alt="delete" title="delete" onclick="DeleteThis('[stable number]', '[dynamic file number]')">
```

The dynamic file number increases per file and should be wildcarded.

I tried...

```
page.find('a[href*="javascript:DeleteThis"]').click #1
first(page.find(:css, "img.pointer", "[alt='delete']")).click  #2
```

both are not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you give all those *<img>*s a common class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selectors are incorrect. [first](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#first-instance_method) doesn't accept Capybara::Element as a parameter. It should be just:

```
page.find(:css, "img.pointer[alt='delete']")
```

or even (if `Capybara.default_selector = :css`):

```
page.find("img.pointer[alt='delete']")
```

It's :css by default.